# Cargo transportation system for loop problem

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQpLx.png)
this has all the detail of the question

how do we print the number of options
we use this formula `options = (cargo / lorrysize) + 1`  this gives us the numbers of options
but after that we are stuck
example cargo size is 100

```
100     100/30=3+1=4
option 1
30
30
30
option 2
30
30
10
10
10
option 3
10x10
option 4
30
10x7
```

second example

```
150      150/30=5+1=6
option 1
30x5
option 2
30x4
10x3
option 3
30x3
10x6
option 4
30x2
10x9
option 5
30
10x12
option 6
10x15
```

we trying to do that but have no idea how to code that the "for loop" part
I hope this is enough for you guys to understand

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <fstream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

/*
Steps to complete program
Step 1: Find total options available (how many Lorrys & Vans) for the input cargo capacity in .txt files
Step 2: For each option, find its:   Amount of Lorrys and Vans
                                     Total cost for both the Lorrys and Vans
                                     Find the max trip
Step 3: Find the top 3 cheapest/lowest cost trips and display
Step 4: Find the fastest available trip and display
*/

class CTS //cargo transport system
{
int i;
    int cargo, lorryprice, vanprice, lorrysize, vansize, allOps;
    //vector<double> options, lorry, vans, totalC, nooftrips;
    //vector <double>::iterator option, minilorry, cost, trips, van;

public:
    void set_cargo(int);
    void set_lorryprice(int);
    void set_vanprice(int);
    void set_lorrysize(int);
    void set_vansize(int);

};
void CTS::set_cargo(int total_cargo){
    cargo = total_cargo;
}
void CTS::set_lorryprice(int lorryP){
    lorryprice = lorryP; 
}

void CTS::set_vanprice(int vanP){
    vanprice = vanP;
}
void CTS::set_lorrysize(int lorryS){
    lorrysize = lorryS;
}
void CTS::set_vansize(int vanS)
{
    vansize = vanS;
}

int main()
{
    int cargo, lorryprice, vanprice, lorrysize, vansize, options, i;
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("size.txt");
    if(infile.is_open()){
        infile >> cargo;
        infile >> lorryprice;
        infile >> vanprice;
        infile >> lorrysize;
        infile >> vansize;
    }
 CTS run;
    run.set_cargo(cargo);
    run.set_lorryprice(lorryprice);
    run.set_vanprice(vanprice);
    run.set_lorrysize(lorrysize);
    run.set_vansize(vansize);

    infile.close();

    options = (cargo / lorrysize) + 1;
    
    
    for (i = 0; i < options; i++)
    {
       

        cout << i << " " << cargo - lorrysize << endl; // this part we need help with we have no clue




    }
    


    /*cout << cargo << endl;
    cout << lorryprice << endl;
    cout << vanprice << endl;
    cout << lorrysize << endl;
    cout << vansize << endl;*/
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, the formula you posted gives you the amount of lorry trips (eg 4L 0V). Now you have to consider what happens if you perform one of those lorry trips with one or more vans. (3L 1V) or even 1L 8V, as in the table in the assignment. Once you generate all those scenarios you can calculate the cost and sort the resulting list by cost.

Comment: As for implementation, think about a `Solution` class or struct that records how many lorries and vans you need, along with a calculation of the cost and amount of trips. Store all your solutions in a `std::vector<Solution>` and you can start sorting by cost or finding the fastest.

Comment: yes we know that but problem is how we do code that in? can at least give an example code? we get the logic we just not sure how to execute it into a code.

Comment: but then we did try using a vector<solution> but the infile ">>" this part got error . is there a way to use vector on file access?

Comment: That is possible, but not commonly done. You do not need it for this assignment.

Comment: question asked to use list/queue/vector though. or is it we misunderstood the question. if so we chose vector how do we implement it onto our code?

Comment: As I said, you would store the **solutions** in a vector. My answer shows you how to generate the solutions individually, it is your task to adapt it to append each solution to that vector.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the maximum number of lorries, you can subtract the lorries' cargo and calculate the number of vans remaining like so:

```
for (int num_lorries = 0; num_lorries < options; num_lorries++) {
    int remaining_cargo = cargo - lorrysize * num_lorries;
    int num_vans = remaining_cargo / vansize;
    // Exercise for you: figure out why this bit is needed.
    // (consider remaining_cargo=25 and vansize = 10)
    if (remaining_cargo % vansize > 0) {
        num_vans++;
    }
    Solution sol(num_lorries, num_vans);
    // Do something with sol
}
```